# Retain formatting while using excerpt [ wp_trim_words() ]

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using `<?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 100); ?>` in my template file to control amount of words to be displayed on a page and also have a link below it for taking user to the next page to read entire content but this function removes all the formatting of content on preview page.

I can't use wordpress default excerpt function here as it is being used elsewhere and i need this to be of different length than that. Is there a way to retain formatting while using this ?

Thanks

**I found a solution to this may be it can help others as well.**

`function content_excerpt($excerpt_length = 5, $id = false, $echo = true) {
    $text = '';
    if($id) {
        $the_post = & get_post( $my_id = $id );
        $text = ($the_post->post_excerpt) ? $the_post->post_excerpt : $the_post->post_content;
    } else {
        global $post;
        $text = ($post->post_excerpt) ? $post->post_excerpt : get_the_content('');
    }
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
        $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
                array_pop($words);
                $text = implode(' ', $words);
                $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
        } else {
                $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }
    if($echo)
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    else
    return $text;
}`

`function get_content_excerpt($excerpt_length = 5, $id = false, $echo = false) {
 return content_excerpt($excerpt_length, $id, $echo);
}`

`// Call function in template file via`

`<?php content_excerpt(50); // 50 is amount to words ?>`

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else facing similar issues, I took the default `wp_trim_words()` function directly out of core, and altered it to not strip tags:

```
function wp_trim_words_retain_formatting( $text, $num_words = 55, $more = null ) {
                    if ( null === $more )
                        $more = __( '&hellip;' );
                    $original_text = $text;
                    /* translators: If your word count is based on single characters (East Asian characters),
                       enter 'characters'. Otherwise, enter 'words'. Do not translate into your own language. */
                    if ( 'characters' == _x( 'words', 'word count: words or characters?' ) && preg_match( '/^utf\-?8$/i', get_option( 'blog_charset' ) ) ) {
                        $text = trim( preg_replace( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", ' ', $text ), ' ' );
                        preg_match_all( '/./u', $text, $words_array );
                        $words_array = array_slice( $words_array[0], 0, $num_words + 1 );
                        $sep = '';
                    } else {
                        $words_array = preg_split( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $num_words + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
                        $sep = ' ';
                    }
                    if ( count( $words_array ) > $num_words ) {
                        array_pop( $words_array );
                        $text = implode( $sep, $words_array );
                        $text = $text . $more;
                    } else {
                        $text = implode( $sep, $words_array );
                    }
                    /**
                     * Filter the text content after words have been trimmed.
                     *
                     * @since 3.3.0
                     *
                     * @param string $text          The trimmed text.
                     * @param int    $num_words     The number of words to trim the text to. Default 5.
                     * @param string $more          An optional string to append to the end of the trimmed text, e.g. &hellip;.
                     * @param string $original_text The text before it was trimmed.
                     */
                    return apply_filters( 'wp_trim_words', $text, $num_words, $more, $original_text );
                }
```

Comment: This function loses the formatting, which is what the OP wanted to avoid. The document is split into words using while space, then combined back together using spaces, regardless of whether words were originally split between paragraphs or not (i.e. multiple newlines).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 100 ) );`

Comment: nope .. same output as i got from above code. No formatting retained (i placed it in my template file replacing the code that i mentioned in my question ... i hope it was correct)